# increment from 1e-3 to 1e-5 in for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I want to increment from 1e-3 to 1e-4 to 1e-5. this would require dividing by 10 but I'm not sure how to do that. Here is what I have written:

```
function wrapper()
    N=50;
    f1 = 1;
    t=10;
    i=0;

    for un = 1e-3:-(un/10):1e-5
        for up = 1e-3:-(up/10):1e-5
            for f2 = 1:0.1:1.2
                i = i + 1;
            end     
        end
    end
    disp(i)
end
```

Comment: Any reason for not doing a for-loop from `1: +1: 3`? It will have an equivalent number of iterations.

Comment: that i = i +1 was just a test to see if my for loop was working

Comment: What I'm getting is you need `1e-3`, `1e-4` and `1e-5` to be accessible in the for-loop. There are very few cases why a simpler equivalent for-loop would not suffice. Unless you're trying to make it increment by a variable amount.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want a list of numbers in which each element is one-tenth of the previous element. You can do that with the following line:

```matlab
10.^[start:-1:stop]
```

Here, `start` is the `log10` of your first value and `stop` is the `log10` of your last value.

In your case, `10.^[-3:-1:-5]` will give you the vector `[1e-3 1e-4 1e-5]`.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logspace.html